# Use AppBar as resource on multiple pages in Universal Windows App

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I would like to use a AppBar on multiple pages as a resource.
I found an MSDN document ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394043(v=vs.105).aspx)) but it's for Windows Phone.

Does anyone know if this is even possible for Universal Apps?

This is how my App.xaml looks like now:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <AppBar x:Key="GlobalBar" ClosedDisplayMode="Minimal">
        <!--Controls....-->
    </AppBar>
</Application.Resources>
```

But how do I implement this on, let's say, MainPage.xaml?

Comment: [This](http://loekvandenouweland.com/content/choosing-a-specific-master-page-for-each-windows-store-app-page) is what i used to solve it (using MasterPages)

Comment: Same as I described in answer plus Navigation manager. Nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest and easiest way to do this is to have a page with the AppBar and a Main Frame.

1. Create a RootPage.
2. Add an Appbar.
3. Add a Frame and name it
       something(ex rootFrame)
4. In the constructor or OnNavigatedTo of
       rootPage navigate the rootFrame to your MainPage.

Now you have an AppBar in all pages. In the pages you can use `this.Frame.Navigate(...)` to navigate. In rootPage where your AppBar is you can `use rootFrame.Navigate(...)`

Comment: Too bad it isn't possible the way i hoped, this feels a bit like going back to WinForms. But thanks for the alternative! Because you also added the navigation option i accepted yours as answer.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer for this question. You'd have to do the same thing if you wanted to use the new UWP SplitView control and have it used on every view.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly you can't do exactly as you want....But you can implement it with a different approach. Use a single master page - add Frame and a single AppBar. The Frame will take care of Page Navigation. I will also suggest you to use commandBar instead of AppBar in UWP apps.
You can use it in MainPage.xaml as -

```
<Page
x:Class="App2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar>

    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
   <!--Your Code-->       
</Grid>
```